# store data kept in json file in a mongodb using pyMongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a json file having 10 lines each line having one dict, containing the data, I want to store this json data in a MongoDB using pyMongo. Here is the code that I have written :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.twitterdata

coll = db.twitterset

f = open('twitterdata.json', 'r')

dblist = []

for line in f:
    dblist.append(line)
```

I am trying to make a list having all the dicts as its elements and then adding it to the collection using `insert_all()` method, but since I am appending the line , will the elements of the list be string or a dict?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have one dict on each line, that's not a valid JSON file. This is not a valid JSON:

```
{"id": 1, "value": "abc"}
{"id": 2, "value": "xyz"}
{"id": 3, "value": "mop"}
```

If you have the data structured like this, I suggest you updating it to a valid JSON like:

```
[{"id": 1,"value": "abc"}, 
 {"id": 2,"value": "xyz"},
 {"id": 3,"value": "mop"}]
```

If you're forced by any reason to stay in the first case, you can make sure you're inserting what you want in the database like this:

```
import json

dblist = []
with open('twitterdata.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        dblist.append(json.loads(line))
```

If you chose to correctly format the file the code gets nicer:

```
import json

dblist = []
with open('twitterdata.json', 'r') as f:
    dblist.extend(json.load(f))
```